# How can I get the ticks to go to the left of the short line of text (see screenshot) HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, ionicons

[Screenshot of ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JtIN.png)

Hi,

As you can see from my screenshot, I am trying to get the blue ticks (which are a font style) to go to the left of the text instead of above the text like in the screenshot.
Here is my code, ignoring the fact I have ionicons v2 font also (https://ionicons.com/v2/) :) 
I've not written many posts, so feel free to ask for more info. 
Thanks All!

```css
.section-monthly-donations {
 background-color: #434343;
}

.plan-box {
 background-color: #696969;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.plan-box div {
 padding: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
}

.plan-box div:last-child {
 text-align: center;
}

.plan-price {
 font-size: 190%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-weight: 200;
 color: #00BFFE;
}

.plan-price span {
 font-size: 70%;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.plan-box ul {
 list-style: none;
}

.plan-box ul li {
 font-size: 70%;
 padding: 5px 0;
}


.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  /*margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;*/
        margin: 0;
 }
}

/*  GRID OF THREE   ============================================================================= */

 
.span-3-of-3 {
 width: 100%; 
}

.span-2-of-3 {
 width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
 width: 32.26%; 
}
```

```html
<section class="section-monthly-donations">
   <div class="row">
    <h2>Pledge a monthly donation</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
     <div class="plan-box">
      <div>
       <h3>Gold</h3>
       <p class="plan-price">£200+ <span>per month</span></p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <ul>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Executive letter signed by the team</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Exclusive access to ...</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Exclusive ...</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-full-light">Pledge now</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
<section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do icons like this in list items.

1. You can add `display: inline` to the `<i>` element in the `<li>` which will make it a part of the list item. Then you can add margin to it if you want to push the content a bit away from the icon.
2. The other way if you don't like the text wrapping with the icon is to make it `position: absolute` and then position the icon inside of a `<li>` that uses `position: relative` and padding to give extra space on the left for the icon.

Snippets below to illustrate both:

```css
.section-monthly-donations {
 background-color: #434343;
}

.plan-box {
 background-color: #696969;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.plan-box div {
 padding: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
}

.plan-box div:last-child {
 text-align: center;
}

.plan-price {
 font-size: 190%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-weight: 200;
 color: #00BFFE;
}

.plan-price span {
 font-size: 70%;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.plan-box ul {
 list-style: none;
}

.plan-box ul li {
 font-size: 70%;
 padding: 5px 0;
}

/* New CSS */
.plan-box ul li i {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
/* End new CSS */


.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  /*margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;*/
        margin: 0;
 }
}

/*  GRID OF THREE   ============================================================================= */

 
.span-3-of-3 {
 width: 100%; 
}

.span-2-of-3 {
 width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
 width: 32.26%; 
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section-monthly-donations">
   <div class="row">
    <h2>Pledge a monthly donation</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
     <div class="plan-box">
      <div>
       <h3>Gold</h3>
       <p class="plan-price">£200+ <span>per month</span></p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <ul>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Executive letter signed by the team</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Exclusive access to ...</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Exclusive ...</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-full-light">Pledge now</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
<section>
```

```css
.section-monthly-donations {
 background-color: #434343;
}

.plan-box {
 background-color: #696969;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.plan-box div {
 padding: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
}

.plan-box div:last-child {
 text-align: center;
}

.plan-price {
 font-size: 190%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-weight: 200;
 color: #00BFFE;
}

.plan-price span {
 font-size: 70%;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.plan-box ul {
 list-style: none;
}

/* Adjusted CSS */
.plan-box ul li {
  position: relative;
 font-size: 70%;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
}
/* End adjusted CSS */

/* New CSS */
.plan-box ul li i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
/* End new CSS */


.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  /*margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;*/
        margin: 0;
 }
}

/*  GRID OF THREE   ============================================================================= */

 
.span-3-of-3 {
 width: 100%; 
}

.span-2-of-3 {
 width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
 width: 32.26%; 
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section-monthly-donations">
   <div class="row">
    <h2>Pledge a monthly donation</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
     <div class="plan-box">
      <div>
       <h3>Gold</h3>
       <p class="plan-price">£200+ <span>per month</span></p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <ul>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Executive letter signed by the team</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Exclusive access to ...</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Exclusive ...</li>
        <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round icon-small"></i>Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-full-light">Pledge now</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
<section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I like the first personally. :)